# Where are the preferences / settings window in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Where did the preferences / settings go in Firefox? I used to go to the menu bar and under "Firefox" is preferences option. I would post the version of Firefox I'm using but I don't know it is because the "About" menu item is also missing from the Firefox menu too!

**Update:**
Using "about:" as suggested, I was able to find that the version is 35.0.8. I'm also using a Mac.

**Update 2:**
I found a button in the lower right hand corner on the Firefox home page. It is still missing from the Firefox title bar menu items which is really what I'm looking for in this question.

[image]

**Update 3:**
I found a button in the upper right corner on new blank web pages. I've added an screenshot.

[image]
**Update 4:**
I found an icon you can add to the tool bar. You can see it here: 
[image]
You have to click customize and then drag the settings icon to the tool bar.

Comment: Type `about:` into the URL bar and hit `Enter` to get what version you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows there are 3 options so far:

- Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the menu bar will show (in the current version it is hidden by default). In the menu bar you can select Tools -> Options.
- Put `about:preferences` into the address bar
- Or as you already suggested in your question: click on the menu button, there you'll find the preferences icon (as of FF V57 the menu changed and now it's in there by default)

For Mac:

- Firefox -> Preferences
- Press <kbd>CMD ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: @1.21gigawatts thangs for the suggstion I added it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Taking the lead from the "about:" suggestion and knowing, "about:config" exists, I tried, "about:preferences" and it opened up a web page with the preferences (not the dialog used in previous versions). It looks like this is the new place for changing your settings.

I've added more locations to original post though it still remains missing from the one place that I wish it was located... the title bar. :(...

Comment: That's not the only way to get there but yes, you can use that method. I didn't suggest it as I figured you were looking for the context menu method. Which normally uses the `Firefox` title bar options menu.